# There is no ordinal $\beta$ such that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha\beta}$ for all ordinals $\alpha > 0$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I met the following problem in my course on Set Theory:

> Prove that there is no ordinal $\beta$ such that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha\beta}$ for all ordinals $\alpha > 0$.

There are no ideas on how to approach it. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an idea and hope I haven't made a mistake anywhere.

Suppose that exists such $\beta$. There are 2 cases:

1. Let $\beta$ $-$ limit ordinal. We can find ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\aleph_\alpha > \beta$. Then we have the following:

$$\aleph_\alpha > \beta \geq cf(\beta) = cf(\alpha\beta) = cf(\aleph_{\alpha\beta}) = cf(2^{\aleph_\alpha}) > \aleph_{\alpha}.$$
Thus we have a contradiction.

2. If $\beta$ is not a limit ordinal, then let’s choose arbitrary limit ordinal $\alpha > \omega$. Then we have the following:

$$\aleph_\alpha \geq \alpha \geq cf(\alpha) = cf(\alpha\beta) \geq cf(\aleph_{\alpha\beta}) = cf(2^{\aleph_\alpha}) > \aleph_{\alpha}.$$
Contradiction again.